# Mysql getting all subject with student name even if id is not there

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below database structure:

### students table

```
      id name gender
       1  abc  male
       2  xyz  female
```

### subjects table

```
       id  name
        1  maths
        2  science
        3  english
```

### studentmarks

```
      id st_id  sub_id marks
       1   1       1    20
       2   1       2    30
       3   2       1    40
```

I want result like this:

```
      name  subjects  marks 
       abc    maths     20
       abc    science   30  
       xyz     maths    40
       abc     english  0
       xyz     science  0
       xyz      english 0
```

Is it possible to achieve above result with MySQL query alone?

---

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
LEFT JOIN studentmarks 
    ON studentmarks.std_id = students.id 
LEFT JOIN subjects 
    ON subjects.id = studentmarks.sub_id
```

The result is not as I want, because I am using `join` so it will only return the matching `id`.

Comment: You need to use a CROSS JOIN between students table and subjects table to get all possible results and LEFT JOIN that result set to the studentmarks table.

Comment: Yes. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @dan08 No, that's not quite correct.

Comment: Oh, the title and question are opposite. I guess the title describes the desired result, but sounds like it is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work

```
SELECT cr.st_name, cr.sub_name, COALESCE(c.marks, 0) 
FROM (SELECT a.id   st_id, 
             a.NAME st_name, 
             b.NAME sub_name, 
             b.id   sub_id 
        FROM students a, 
             subjects b) cr 
LEFT JOIN studentmarks c
    ON cr.sub_id = c.sub_id 
    AND c.st_id = cr.st_id
```

Comment: This worked !! thanks alot, if you dont mind can u pls explain the query also  especially "(select a.id st_id,a.name st_name,b.name sub_name, b.id sub_id from students a , subjects b) cr " this line or give a reference so that i can read and understand it

Comment: You are wellcome.

(select a.id st_id,a.name st_name,b.name sub_name, b.id sub_id from students a , subjects b) cr

This subquery returns cartesian product of students and subjects tables because it has no 'where' or 'on' condition. Result have all possible student subject pairs. 

Coalesce and left join do the rest.

Comment: You know, these queries return same result;

"select * from students, subjects" 

"select * from students join subjects on 1=1"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result using following query

```
SELECT SM.marks, 
    S.NAME AS Student_name, 
    SBJ.NAME as Subject
FROM  studentmarks AS SM 
JOIN students AS S ON SM.st_id = S.id 
JOIN subjects AS SBJ ON SM.sub_id = SBJ.id
```

You can also use CROSS join as well I guess if you want to stick with your current query

Comment: Sorry but this is also not giving the desired result.

Comment: What result are you getting using this query?Any fields are missing?

Comment: Just getting the first 3 rows of the result, the remaining is not coming

Comment: Your student marks table only has 3 rows. You could create rows in student marks with zero value. Or you could write code in PHP (your preferred language) to show 0 value rows where mysql does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try that one

```
SELECT A.name, B.name, C.marks
FROM students A, subjects B, studentmarks C
WHERE A.id = C.st_id AND B.id = C.sub_id;
```